# "she held it close to other nominees who did not directly answer the question"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

This is from [a news podcast](https://www.npr.org/2022/03/23/1088169655/morning-news-brief).

> MARTINEZ: Now, she was also asked about her views on constitutional
> cases that protect abortion rights. The court is currently considering
> a challenge to Roe v. Wade that's going to be decided later this year.
> What did she have to say about that?
>
> DAVIS: You know, she **held it close to** other nominees who did not
> directly answer the question, but she also notably aligned herself
> with how recently confirmed conservative judges have answered the same
> question.

I wonder what 'held it close to' in bold means in the above context.

My sense is that it means 'kept it to herself like (someone)'.

Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure that's grammatical.

Comment: @Mary Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a verbal mistake that happens when speaking off the cuff. The expression that was probably intended was:

> **she held it close to her chest**

which is a shortening of

> **she held her cards close to her chest**

which means "she didn't reveal her intentions".

Comment: Thank you very much.